# What's does "machine byte order" in PHP pack mean?

Tags: php, pack

I understand little & big endian, but What's "machine byte order" mean?

Comment: is this a question or a statement?

Comment: It means the byte order of the machine it's running on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When would you use unpack('h*' ...) or pack('h*' ...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857499/when-would-you-use-unpackh-or-packh)

Comment: It means PHP will pack in whatever order the underlying machine it's running on uses, meaning pack will produce different results on different platforms, using the exact same code.

Comment: @MarcB so, for unpack() this doesn't affect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) the phrase "machine byte order" means that the endianess is determined by the *current machine*<sup>1</sup>

PHP itself makes *no guarantees* as to which endianness such characters (e.g. `S`, `L`) encode data, except as the ordering relates to the *current machine*.

Therefor, be cautious with using "machine byte order" pack characters and consider the *guaranteed-order* counter-parts (e.g. `n`, `v`) if there is every any doubt<sup>1</sup>. However, pay attention to the *target data specification* as some silly formats like [Microsoft] UUIDs are laid out in terms of "machine byte order" while others are always big-endian or always little-endian.

---

<sup>1</sup> x86/x64 is always little-endian, but PHP could technically run on big-endian machines .. somewhere. It is best to get into the habit of being explicit and precise to avoid having code suddenly and mysteriously "stop working" later on.