# Is machine byte order affect to unpack function?

Tags: php, unpack

Is machine byte order affect to unpack function in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12430799/438971

Comment: @Orbling That's my question too :D

Comment: LOL, so it is.  Obviously you did not get what you wanted out of it the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine byte order is affect to unpack function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Comment: As far as I know, machine byte order is necessary for packing bytes